# How to improve python dict performance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, dictionary

I recently coded a python solution using dictoionaries which got TLE verdict. The solution is exactly similar to a multiset solution in c++ which works. So, we are sure that the logic is correct, but the implementation is not upto the mark.

The problem description for understanding below code (http://codeforces.com/contest/714/problem/C):

- For each number we need to get a string of 0s and 1s such that i'th digit is 0/1 if respective ith digit in number is even/odd.
- We need to maintain the count of number that have the same mapping that is given by above described point.

Any hints/pointer to improve the performance of below code? It gave TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) for a large test case(http://codeforces.com/contest/714/submission/20594344).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getPattern(s):
    return ''.join(list(s.zfill(19)))

def getSPattern(s):
    news = s.zfill(19)
    patlist = [ '0' if (int(news[i])%2 == 0) else '1'   for i in range(19) ]
    return "".join(patlist)


t = int(raw_input())
pat = defaultdict(str)  # holds strings as keys and int as value

for i in range(0, t):
    oper, num = raw_input().strip().split(' ')

    if oper == '+' :
        pattern = getSPattern(str(num))
        if pattern in pat:
            pat[pattern] += 1
        else:
            pat[pattern] = 1
    elif oper == '-' :
        pattern = getSPattern(str(num))
        pat[pattern] =  max( pat[pattern] - 1, 0)
    elif oper == '?' :
        print pat.get(getPattern(num) , 0 )
```

Comment: While not an expert in perf-tuning, I would expect dictionary lookup performance to be quite high. I would be inclined into looking more into that `getSPattern` function, as I believe something can be squeezed out of there. Now, before we even start, I read the contest, but couldn't get where the time limit gets measured: is it just at the '? <pattern>' test?

Comment: @sal time limit is measured per test case execution. So for a large test case where the input number is t give TLE for 100000. If you scroll to the very bottom of the submission link you can check this.

Comment: Got it. Give this version a try: https://eval.in/641639 where I have changed your `getSPattern` only, and got rid of `defaultdict` (although you could keep it). See if that gives you any boost in performance. If yes, then I'll add an answer with more details about it.

Comment: will definitely give a try as soon as my machine recovers from this failure :) http://askubuntu.com/q/824585/56429

Comment: @sal I was not making use of defaultdict correctly. Your code got accepted. http://codeforces.com/contest/714/submission/20615167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see lots of small problems with your code but can't say if they add up to significant performance issues:

You've set up, and used, your `defaultdict()` incorrectly:

```
pat = defaultdict(str)
...
if pattern in pat:
    pat[pattern] += 1
else:
    pat[pattern] = 1
```

The argument to the `defaultdict()` constructor should be the type of the values, not the keys.  Once you've set up your defaultdict properly, you can simply do:

```
pat = defaultdict(int)
...
pat[pattern] += 1
```

As the value will now default to zero if the pattern isn't there already.

Since the specification says:

> -  ai — delete a single occurrence of non-negative integer ai from the multiset. It's guaranteed, that there is at least one ai in the
>   multiset.

Then this:

```
pat[pattern] =  max( pat[pattern] - 1, 0)
```

can simply be this:

```
pat[pattern] -= 1
```

You're working with 19 character strings but since the specification says the numbers will be less than 10 ** 18, you can work with 18 character strings instead.

`getSPattern()` does a `zfill()` and then processes the string, it should do it in the reverse order, process the string and then `zfill()` it, as there's no need to run the logic on the leading zeros.

We don't need the overhead of `int()` to convert the characters to numbers:

```
(int(news[i])%2 == 0)
```

Consider using `ord()` instead as the ASCII values of the digits have the same parity as the digits themselves: `ord('4')` -> 52

And you don't need to loop over the indexes, you can simply loop over the characters.

Below is my rework of your code with the above changes, see if it still works (!) and gains you any performance:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getPattern(string):
    return string.zfill(18)

def getSPattern(string):
    # pattern_list = (('0', '1')[ord(character) % 2] for character in string)
    pattern_list = ('0' if ord(character) % 2 == 0 else '1' for character in string)
    return ("".join(pattern_list)).zfill(18)

patterns = defaultdict(int)  # holds keys as strings as and values as int

text = int(raw_input())

for _ in range(text):
    operation, number = raw_input().strip().split()

    if operation == '+':
        pattern = getSPattern(number)
        patterns[pattern] += 1
    elif operation == '-':
        pattern = getSPattern(number)
        patterns[pattern] -= 1
    elif operation == '?':
        print patterns.get(getPattern(number), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant inputs, Surprised to see so many flaws in my code :). Your version got accepted http://codeforces.com/contest/714/submission/20615068

Answer (score 2):

With the explanation already done by @cdlane, I just need to add my rewrite of `getSPattern` where I think the bulk of time is spent. As per my initial comment this is available on https://eval.in/641639

```
def getSPattern(s):
    patlist = ['0' if c in ['0', '2', '4', '6', '8'] else '1' for c in s]
    return "".join(patlist).zfill(19)
```

Using zfill(18) might marginally spare you some time.

Comment: I'd use `patstr = ''.join(chr(0x30 + ord(c)&1) for c in s)`

Comment: @MarkRansom that's cool, I'll try it out, but no need to use hex: `[chr(48+(ord(c)&1)) for c in s]`